# How can setTimeout() and setInterval() affect each other?

Tags: javascript, timer, settimeout, dom-events, setinterval

I am writing my first website, where a user's goal is to choose an object with the fastest bpm(rhythm). There are 2 big objects with 2 different bpm's, each of them is activated when you place a cursor on it (i use event listener with mouseover).

I decided to make a delay between "rhythm switching" because when a user moves his cursor quickly from one object to another, the next rhythm plays immediately and it feels uncomfortable.

But with code below the whole rhythm playing system breaks and rhythm starts playing even if the cursor is not hovering over the object (it happens if you quickly move the cursor over and back again the object several times). Clearing the interval of the timer used for rhythm playing doesn't help.

If the commented part is uncommented and the "if" part is commented, then everything works fine but I don't get the delay.

`t0` is a time measured when `mouseout` event happens. `play_bpm1` is a function executed on `mouseover` event for the first object. There is the same function for the second object. pla() is used to play one beat immediately, play(bpm) is a function using pla() with setInterval, so when executed rhythm starts playing. rtimer is a timer which is used in play(bpm) with setInterval.

```
var play_bpm1 = function(){ 
    if(performance.now()-t0 <= (60000/bpm2)){ //delay between rhythm switching
        rdelay1 = setTimeout(function(){
            clearInterval(rtimer);
            pla();
            play_rt(bpm1);
        }, (60000/bpm2)-(performance.now()-t0) )    
    }
    else{
        clearInterval(rtimer);
        pla();
        play_rt(bpm1);
    }

    // pla();
    // play_rt(bpm1);
}
```

Comment: You should edit the question to add details, not put them in comments.

Comment: You should look up "debouncing" to see how to prevent an event handler from running too frequently.